# Generate new post WordPress based on MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have created a Wordpress page to show dynamic content based on MySQL database. The content will be shown based on the URL parameter.

Ex: https://domainname.com/hotel-details/?hotelcode=First-Hotel

Is it possible to generate a new post for each database row? 
So, instead of using an URL parameter like one above, the URL could be: https://domainname.com/hotel-details/First-Hotel

I created this dynamic page by inserting a PHP code to a Wordpress page (I use Advanced Ads plugin to insert the code)

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['hotelcode']))
{
$hotelcode = $_GET['hotelcode'];
}
else
{
$hotelcode = "";  
}
include 'dbconnect.php'; // MySQL DB connection
$dbconnect = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);
$dbresult = mysqli_query($dbconnect, "
SELECT * 
  FROM HotelDatabase 
 WHERE HotelSlug='$hotelcode' 
");
foreach ($dbresult as $row);
$HotelName= $row['HotelName']; $HotelDetail= $row['HotelDetail']; 
$Image= $row['Image']; $Review= $row['Review'];

?>

<?php if($dbresult->num_rows == 0) 
 {
 echo "<h1 style='text-align: center;'>No Data Found</h1>
 } 
 else 
{
echo "
<br><br>
<h1 style='text-align: center; color: blue;'>$Hotel Name</h1>
<img src='$Image'><br>
$HotelDetail<br>
$Review
";       
 }
?>
```

I have no problem to display the content on the page, what I want is, show the content on the new generated pages for each database row instead of using a unique URL parameter.

Change 
https://domainname.com/hotel-details/?hotelcode=First-Hotel
to
https://domainname.com/hotel-details/First-Hotel

Comment: See about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries

Comment: I think you're just looking for a URL rewrite module

Comment: @Strawberry I am not familiar with the URL rewrite module, would you provide some sources?